# Start build after finishing some others

Tags: jenkins

We have some builds that depents on each other in a kind of tree structure:

- A

  - AA
  - AB

    - ABA
  - AC
- B

  - BA
  - BB

    - BBA

      - BBAA

        - BBAAA
      - BBAB
- C

...

Another build should be triggered if **all** of these builds have finished. Unfortunatelly it is not possible to say which build will be always the last that finished to use this to trigger the following task.

Is there a chance (maybe a plugin) that allows to trigger a new build when **each** build of a list of builds has finished?

Thanks in advance!
Frank

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Join Plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

> This plugin allows a job to be run after all the immediate downstream
>   jobs have completed.   In this way,  the execution can branch out and
>   perform many steps in parallel, and then run a final aggregation step
>   just once after all the parallel work is finished.

Comment: seems that the Join Plugin cannot do this at the moment (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9946 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11274)?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if it's suitable for this case, but you could possibly also do this with the Build Flow Plugin.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, the Build Flow Plugin solved our problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, you might consider restructuring your build pipeline completely using the Build Flow Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

It will have the advantage of keeping your pipeline logic in one place.